# ASPX works locally but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have uploaded a web project on the server.

While it was running smoothly on my local pc where the development was made, it's not running at all on the server. As far as I can read the error, theres' a problem with an empty DataSet (fetches data from a SQL db). Again, when running the aspx locally everything is ok. Another issue I see on the errorlog is it points to my local drive "D:..." Shouldn't it point to the server address?

Error.

```
There is no row at position 0.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.]
   System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex) +2474798
   System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +21
   WEB.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\dev\Visual Studio\Temp\WEB\Default.aspx.cs:59
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

Any idea? I use the publish tool from VS2010 and it succesfully uploads in the server. But it's not working.

Another thing I don't get is, why the webpage sends this error if I have a try/catch in the page load. If there's an error, it sets a Label with a friendly message.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's the page load code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["FlagOpen"] = false;
                var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                if (windowsIdentity != null)
                {
                    var userName = windowsIdentity.Name;
                    userName = Regex.Replace(userName, ".*\\\\(.*)", "$1", RegexOptions.None);
                    var ds = _objUser.GetRanking(userName);
                    var ranking = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    _objPersona.Ranking = ranking;
                    _objPersona.UserName = userName;
                    _objPersona.RealName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    Session["User"] = _objPersona;
                    LblUserName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    ds = _objUser.GetFAQ(userName);
                    var cant = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;                        
                }
                else
                {
                    BtnAbrirBandeja.Enabled = false;
                    LblUserName.Text = "Not allowed.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LblWarnings.Text = "Error. Please contact sysadmin.";
            throw;
        }

    }
```

**EDIT 2.**

Page keeps working locally. But not on the server. It throws the original error pointing to a local folder (when it's already uploaded and running from the server).
The DataSet being null is a consequence of the web not being able to communicate with the SQL server. Hence the error.
Basically, it runs OK while debugging, but not on server.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Without some source to look at its hard to tell.

Comment: silly question, but is the database accessible from the server?

Comment: @PhonicUK If it's needed I can show you the Page_Load, but since it works (locally) I assumed it would be a more general error on the local/server aspx stuff.

Comment: @Jay I know of other webprojects from that same server accessing that particular SQL db, so I assume yes. Will check though.

Comment: Why are you abusing the `var` keyword?  `var` is to be used mainly for linq expressions or unknown datatypes, but come on already for `datasets` and `strings` too ?

Comment: @JonH Resharper advice, didn't think it was that much of a struggle.

Comment: That advice is very bad advice sorry.

Comment: @JonH will re-work the var's in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test your dataset for `null` before you try to access an `element` from the dataset, hence the error message:

```
if (ds!=null)
 { 
  //continue and access the dataset
 }
else
 {
  //you didn't get any data or ds is simply null (result set is null)
 }
```

You are also misusing the `var` keyword, you don't need to use `var` for simple types like strings and datasets.

Comment: JonH. Besides the ds being null and the var's. Do you know why the error is pointing to my local development folder? The project is already uploaded to the server... I'm kind of lost with that.

Comment: Maybe you didnt deploy the solution correctly?  That is a strange one that I think I've seen before just don't remember how it was resolved.  If you find an answer before I do post it back here so we all know!

Comment: It was anonymous login and stuff. The project wasnt able to get the Windows/domain so that was the spark. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason your data is inaccessible or doesn't exist:

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.]

var ranking = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

You need to be checking `ds.Tables.length` (or count as it may be) before performing that line.

Answer (score 1):

May be when running on your local machine it was taking data from your local server and now its getting data from your server database engine..tables may be empty there or may be tables not exist there..
Check your dataset fetching method for any errors..your try catch might have hidden that error..

your another part of question:

It throws that exception because your catch block has a 'throw' statement, which will just through the same error catched by the catch block with all the inner exception details..

Note: if you write 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {throw ex;}

inner exception details would be lost...